# Customizable, canonical URL for Solspace Tag entries

Tags: solspace, low-variables, seo, solspace-tag

I'm using Solspace Tag to display a bunch of entries by particular tag. What I need to do is to set a Canonical URL for this list of entries. The Canonical URL might be to a completely different page.

Because the Solspace Tag {exp:tag:entries} is effectively not a real page, I was wondering if anyone might have an idea how I would go about this?

My first thought would be to somehow use Low Variables to set a specific Canonical URL for a {exp:tag:entries} 'page'.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your goal - why can't you just create a template group/template and use that, just as you would any Channel Entries or other EE tag?

Comment: A {exp:tag:entries} isn't an actual page that you can edit in admin. So if i set a url that way, it would apply to every tag.

Comment: But it would be dynamic, just like any Channel Entries tag - think of the "websafe tag" as the "URL title". e.g., `/news/entry/hello-world` (Channel entry), `/news/tag/company+news` (Tag entry).

Comment: I suppose the thing I can't see how to do is if the Tag entry is /news/tag/company+news I might want the canonical URL to be /news/category/company-news (for example).

Comment: Just set the `websafe_separator` parameter on both `tag:tags` and `tag:entries` to `"-"`.

Comment: Sorry, that was probably a bad example. If I wanted to add a canonical url of /some-other-page for the /news/tag/company+news tag entry.

Comment: Ah, I see - and you want your client to be able to add/edit these URLs?

Comment: That's right. :)